# How to manage Joins in hadoop - MultipleInputPath

Tags: java, join, hadoop, mapreduce

After a map side join the data I am getting in Reducer is

```
key------ book
values
    6
    eraser=>book 2
    pen=>book 4
    pencil=>book 5
```

What I basically want to do is

```
eraser=>book = 2/6
pen=>book = 4/6
pencil=>book = 5/6
```

What I initially did is like

```
public void reduce(Text key,Iterable<Text> values , Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

        System.out.println("key------ "+key);
        System.out.println("Values");
        for(Text value : values){
            System.out.println("\t"+value.toString());
            String v = value.toString();
            double BsupportCnt = 0;
            double UsupportCnt = 0;
            double res = 0;
            if(!v.contains("=>")){
                BsupportCnt = Double.parseDouble(v);
            }
            else{
                String parts[] = v.split(" ");
                UsupportCnt = Double.parseDouble(parts[1]);
            }
//          calculate here
            res = UsupportCnt/BsupportCnt;

        }
```

If incoming data is as above then this works fine

But if the incoming data from mapper is

```
key------ book
values
    eraser=>book 2
    pen=>book 4
    pencil=>book 5
    6
```

This wont work
Or else I need to store all `=>` in a List (If the incoming data is a large data, the list may caught Heap space) and once I get a number I should do the calculation.

**UPDATE**
As Vefthym asked to do secondary sorting the values before it reaches the reducer.
I used `htuple` to do the same.
I reffered [this link](http://grepalex.com/2013/10/07/secondary-sort-with-htuple/)

In mapper1 emits `eraser=>book 2` as value
So

```
public class AprioriItemMapper1 extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Tuple>{
    public void map(Text key,Text value,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        //Configurations and other stuffs
        //allWords is an ArrayList
        if(allWords.size()<=2)
        {
            Tuple outputKey = new Tuple();
            String LHS1 = allWords.get(1);
            String RHS1 = allWords.get(0)+"=>"+allWords.get(1)+" "+value.toString();
            outputKey.set(TupleFields.ALPHA, RHS1);
            context.write(new Text(LHS1), outputKey);
                 }
//other stuffs
```

Mapper2 emits `numbers` as value

```
public class AprioriItemMapper2 extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Tuple>{
    Text valEmit = new Text(); 
    public void map(Text key,Text value,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        //Configuration and other stuffs
        if(cnt != supCnt && cnt < supCnt){
            System.out.println("emit");
            Tuple outputKey = new Tuple();
            outputKey.set(TupleFields.NUMBER, value);

            System.out.println("v---"+value);
            System.out.println("outputKey.toString()---"+outputKey.toString());
            context.write(key, outputKey);
        }
```

Reducer I simply tried to print key and values

But this caught error

```
Mapper 2: 
line book
Support Count: 2
count--- 1
emit
v---6
outputKey.toString()---[0]='6, 
14/08/07 13:54:19 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Map task executor complete.
14/08/07 13:54:19 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local626380383_0003
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.htuple.Tuple
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:406)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.htuple.Tuple
    at org.htuple.TupleMapReducePartitioner.getPartition(TupleMapReducePartitioner.java:28)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:106)
    at edu.am.bigdata.apriori.AprioriItemMapper1.map(AprioriItemMapper1.java:49)
    at edu.am.bigdata.apriori.AprioriItemMapper1.map(AprioriItemMapper1.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.DelegatingMapper.run(DelegatingMapper.java:51)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:672)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:268)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Err is at   `context.write(new Text(LHS1), outputKey);` from `AprioriItemMapper1.java:49`
but the above printing details are from Mapper 2

Any better way to do this
Please Suggest.

Comment: where is 6 coming from? Could it be a part of the key? What do you do with `res` after it is computed?

Comment: Secondary sorting (sorting reducer's input by value) might help you guarantee that the first value will be the `BsupportCnt`, since a number is lexicographically smaller than any letter.

Comment: Vefthym this is as part of Apriori Rule generation where res is confidence

Comment: Vefthym: But I am using 2 mappers. One mapper emit numeric value and the other like this  eraser=>book 2. So can we use Secondary Sorting along with that

Comment: I don't see a reason why not, if I am not missing something.

Comment: I have not used htuple, but I believe that you should emit your `outputKey`s as keys and not values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58858/discussion-between-sreeveni-and-vefthym).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using secondary sorting, which would guarantee that the first value (sorted lexicographically) is a numeric one, supposing there are no words starting with a number.

If this cannot work, then, bearing the scalability limitations that you mention, I would store the reducer's values in a `HashMap<String,Double>` buffer with keys being the left parts of "=>" and values being their numeric values. 
You can store the values, until you get the value of the denominator `BsupportCnt`. Then you can emit all the buffer's contents with the correct score and all the remaining values, as they come one-by-one, without the need to use the buffer again (since you now know the denominator). Something like that:

```
public void reduce(Text key,Iterable<Text> values , Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    Map<String,Double> buffer = new HashMap<>();
    double BsupportCnt = 0;
    double UsupportCnt;
    double res;
    for(Text value : values){
        String v = value.toString();

        if(!v.contains("=>")){
            BsupportCnt = Double.parseDouble(v);
        } else {
            String parts[] = v.split(" ");
            UsupportCnt = Double.parseDouble(parts[1]);

            if (BsupportCnt != 0) { //no need to add things to the buffer any more
               res = UsupportCnt/BsupportCnt;
               context.write(new Text(v), new DoubleWritable(res));
            } else {
               buffer.put(parts[0], UsupportCnt);
            }
        }

    }


    //now emit the buffer's contents
    for (Map<String,Double>.Entry entry : buffer) {
        context.write(new Text(entry.getKey()), new DoubleWritable(entry.getValue()/BsupportCnt));
    }
}
```

You could gain some more space by storing only the left part of "=>" as keys of the HashMap, as the right part is always the reducer's input key.

Comment: vefthym, one more doubt- does this buffer can also catch heapspace? Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Correct, if values met, until finding the denominator are bigger than the heap size.